# Chinese (intelligent pinyin) is not working well

Tags: 18.04, chinese, pinyin

when selecting target Chinese character's number, it will display the number instead of the character I needed. Any thoughts?

Ubuntu Version:18.04, Desktop, ibus Libpinyin

e.g. when selecting the third one, it will display as 证件3
[image: when selecting the third one, it will display as 证件3]

Comment: Ubuntu Version:18.04, Desktop, ibus Libpinyin

Comment: All right, re-installed Ubuntu Kylin, which is more suitable for Chinese

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours after installing some updates yesterday. You can shut down ibus intelligent pinyin and install `fcitx-googlepinyin` through apt-get.

In **Regions and Languages > Manage Installed Languages -> Keyboard Input System** change it to *fcitx* from *ibus*. Reboot.

Now you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between input system instead of <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. I don't know if `googlepinyin` has some other incompatibilities, but as far as I can see it doesn't have the problem `ibus-libpinyin` has that bothered us.

Comment: for me `fcitx-googlepinyin` broke my whole ubuntu installation, couldn't startup anymore